# SOAP server crashes when sending a request

Tags: c#, soap, soap-client

I have a SOAP server that I need to request and send commands to.

First I developed just a listener and printed the data to the console to see if the server is publishing correctly to the right port number and it works here is my code:

```
class listener
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 9005.
            Int32 port = 9005;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while (true)
            {

                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

PS:
1/server write to port number 9005 and listen on port 9003.
2/ There is no WSDL available.

Now I have this request sample from the server documentation that I need to test:

```
POST /ot HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Dispatcher
Host: localhost:9003
Content-Length: 226
Connection: Close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <startPSF/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I implemented this SOAP client class but the server is crashing and the app tabs are closing when sending the request! Here is my code:

```
class SOAPClient
{
    public static void CallWebService()
    {
        var _url = "http://localhost:9003/ot";
        var _action = "http://localhost:9003/ot?op=startPSF";

        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
        InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

        // begin async call to web request.
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

        asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

        // get the response from the completed web request.
        string soapResult;

        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
        {           
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Console.Write(soapResult);
            webResponse.Close();
            
        }
        webRequest.Abort();
    }

    private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
    {

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        webRequest.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
        webRequest.Host = "localhost:9003";
        //webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Dispatcher";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentLength = 226;
        //webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        webRequest.KeepAlive = false;

        return webRequest;
    }

    private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
    {
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeDocument = new XmlDocument();

        soapEnvelopeDocument.LoadXml(
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    <startPSF/>
                </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");

        return soapEnvelopeDocument;
    }

    private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallWebService();
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=System.Net.Requests
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at soapClient.CallWebService() in C:\Users\pfsClient\soapClient.cs:line 39
   at soapClient.Main() in C:\Users\pfsClient\soapClient.cs:line 117

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I also tried without async calls and same error!

PS: I can see with netstat that the server is listening on 0.0.0.0:9003 but when I try with this IP Address instead of localhost:9003 I got this error:

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and IPv6 address ::0 are unspecified addresses that cannot be used as a target address. (Parameter 'hostName') (0.0.0.0:9002)
  Source=System.Net.Requests
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at soapClient.CallWebService() in C:\Users\pfsClient\soapClient.cs:line 39
   at soapClient.Main() in C:\Users\pfsClient\soapClient.cs:line 117

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and IPv6 address ::0 are unspecified addresses that cannot be used as a target address. (Parameter 'hostName') (0.0.0.0:9002)

Inner Exception 2:
ArgumentException: IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and IPv6 address ::0 are unspecified addresses that cannot be used as a target address. (Parameter 'hostName')
```

After adding proxy (GetEmptyWebProxy), httpVersion and content-type:
Now I am getting a Time-Out error:

```
System.Net.WebException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The operation has timed out.
  Source=System.Net.Requests
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at soapClient.CallWebService() in C:\Users\pfsClient\soapClient.cs:line 39
   at soapClient.Main() in C:\Users\pfsClient\soapClient.cs:line 113
```

Comment: It seems your server does not send a response

Comment: But why it crashes if it doesn't send a response it should at least execute the command sent ? and the documentation says that it executes the command and send an "ack" that "PSF STARTED" in an xml format!
My guess is that I have a problem in formatting the http header ?

Comment: You say the server crashes but show us only the exception on client side (which says that the client expects a response but does not get one).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to server exceptions!

Comment: So why do you think it crashed?

Comment: My guess is that I have a problem in formatting the HTTP-HEADER or the SOAP-DATA ?